# Does Graphview allow setting ticks on x- or y-axis?

Tags: android, android-graphview

I want to make unequal tick marks on y-axis. Graphview generally gives .setNumVerticalLabales(int) and divides the minY and maxY based on the int number given. But I want to mark unequal ticks based on the frequency numbers generated. For example: for a range of 90 to 400 on y-axis, 97.99 is the first tick, 103.83, the second and so on for 25 ticks. is that possible? It can be a rounded 98, 104, etc. Not necessary to have double.

Comment: No response yet?